# Why shouldn't use setRetainInstance if I use DialogFragment in order to keep the dialog displayed after configuration changes ?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

just need to figure this out. We all know that fragments are attractive in such situations where configuration changes like screen orientation change occur.

This is because **Fragments** are **retained** across Activity destruction and recreation and attached to the newly created Activity almost every time if there's a call to the *setRetainInstance(true)* from the *onCreate()* Fragment method.

So why it is not the same for the DialogFragment? I mean even if there's no call to the *setRetainInstance(true)* the dialog is retained across Activity's configuration changes.

Could someone explain me this little difference between a Fragment and a DialogFragment?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What differences did you see between a normal Fragment and a DialogFragment after a configuration change? *This is because Fragments are retained across Activity destruction and recreation and attached to the newly created Activity almost every time* - and if you don't use `setRetainInstance()` you lose fragments or what?

Comment: The basic difference is that without using the setRetainInstance on the DialogFragment the dialog is retained however and I keep see it displayed. Instead, using a Fragment implies using the setRetainInstance in order to keep the fragment retained across configuration changes and not re-created. Why the first (DialogFragment) is retained implicitly and the second (a normal Fragment) must have the setRetainInstance(true) called in the onCreate()?

Comment: But the dialog is recreated after a rotation if you don't use setRetainInstance(). You still see the dialog because the DialogFragment restores the dialog on its own. setRetainInstance() is used to keep the current fragment(normal or dialog) instance alive between a configuration change so you end up with the same object.

Comment: @Luksprog Do all types of fragments (and not just dialogFragment) get re-created upon configuration changes, even if the activity created them only once?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes they get recreated. It doesn't matter if the activity created them only once, if they are in the FragmentManager at the moment of the configuration change they need to be available after so they get recreated.